# .NET Core 7 keycloak jwt token integration

Tags: c#, .net-core, jwt, keycloak, bearer-token

I am using Keycloak for my ASP.NET Core 7 Web API application.

My keycloak settings are as follows.

```
{
  "allowRemoteResourceManagement": true,
  "policyEnforcementMode": "ENFORCING",
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "res:bot",
      "type": "urn:app-client:resources:bot",
      "ownerManagedAccess": false,
      "displayName": "res:bot",
      "attributes": {},
      "_id": "0190385a-890a-4876-8e07-bf29c4c91466",
      "uris": [],
      "scopes": [
        {
          "name": "scopes:view"
        },
        {
          "name": "scopes:create"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "res:report",
      "type": "urn:app-client:resources:report",
      "ownerManagedAccess": false,
      "displayName": "res:report",
      "attributes": {},
      "_id": "7897680c-d0b6-4fba-8730-5ddbd891c68b",
      "uris": [],
      "scopes": [
        {
          "name": "scopes:view"
        },
        {
          "name": "scopes:create"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "res:account",
      "type": "urn:app-client:resources:account",
      "ownerManagedAccess": false,
      "displayName": "res:account",
      "attributes": {},
      "_id": "ecca2ad1-06ad-490e-af8a-305ebd293591",
      "uris": [],
      "scopes": [
        {
          "name": "scopes:view"
        },
        {
          "name": "scopes:create"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "policies": [
    {
      "id": "91001e4e-63c3-4b70-baf3-86af35f3b0ce",
      "name": "Admin",
      "description": "Admin role required",
      "type": "role",
      "logic": "POSITIVE",
      "decisionStrategy": "UNANIMOUS",
      "config": {
        "roles": "[{\"id\":\"admin\",\"required\":false}]"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "e2d067e2-fd49-4c15-90a5-e033aad2e535",
      "name": "Agent",
      "description": "Agent role is required",
      "type": "role",
      "logic": "POSITIVE",
      "decisionStrategy": "UNANIMOUS",
      "config": {
        "roles": "[{\"id\":\"agent\",\"required\":false}]"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "b469d005-c834-4d0d-8d1e-ffb9331f2814",
      "name": "Super_admin",
      "description": "super_admin role is required",
      "type": "role",
      "logic": "POSITIVE",
      "decisionStrategy": "UNANIMOUS",
      "config": {
        "roles": "[{\"id\":\"super_admin\",\"required\":false}]"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "a62d1754-e2ca-4684-b6af-4b3e0e179ad2",
      "name": "Admin or Super_admin or Agent",
      "description": "Admin or Super_admin or Agent role required",
      "type": "aggregate",
      "logic": "POSITIVE",
      "decisionStrategy": "AFFIRMATIVE",
      "config": {
        "applyPolicies": "[\"Agent\",\"Super_admin\",\"Admin\"]"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "15af97cd-b591-4655-8233-434849774c6d",
      "name": "report-create",
      "type": "scope",
      "logic": "POSITIVE",
      "decisionStrategy": "UNANIMOUS",
      "config": {
        "resources": "[\"res:report\"]",
        "scopes": "[\"scopes:create\"]",
        "applyPolicies": "[\"Super_admin\"]"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "3b4cef1b-95fe-416c-8a07-cdee9d068140",
      "name": "report-view",
      "type": "scope",
      "logic": "POSITIVE",
      "decisionStrategy": "UNANIMOUS",
      "config": {
        "resources": "[\"res:report\"]",
        "scopes": "[\"scopes:view\"]",
        "applyPolicies": "[\"Admin or Super_admin or Agent\"]"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "9f89e570-ccdf-4277-b4eb-2a28d0db0408",
      "name": "account-create",
      "type": "scope",
      "logic": "POSITIVE",
      "decisionStrategy": "UNANIMOUS",
      "config": {
        "resources": "[\"res:account\"]",
        "scopes": "[\"scopes:create\"]",
        "applyPolicies": "[\"Admin\"]"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "bb56f7ff-15d4-4dc4-bd6f-7e61d5d5c4f9",
      "name": "bot-view",
      "type": "scope",
      "logic": "POSITIVE",
      "decisionStrategy": "UNANIMOUS",
      "config": {
        "resources": "[\"res:bot\"]",
        "scopes": "[\"scopes:view\"]",
        "applyPolicies": "[\"Admin or Super_admin or Agent\"]"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "bf95254f-9e0c-4651-81c3-428516f394a0",
      "name": "bot-create",
      "type": "scope",
      "logic": "POSITIVE",
      "decisionStrategy": "UNANIMOUS",
      "config": {
        "resources": "[\"res:bot\"]",
        "scopes": "[\"scopes:create\"]",
        "applyPolicies": "[\"Admin\"]"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "d2e48a4d-7617-4ba9-ae2f-0a7ade5f591b",
      "name": "account-view",
      "type": "scope",
      "logic": "POSITIVE",
      "decisionStrategy": "UNANIMOUS",
      "config": {
        "resources": "[\"res:account\"]",
        "scopes": "[\"scopes:view\"]",
        "applyPolicies": "[\"Admin or Super_admin or Agent\"]"
      }
    }
  ],
  "scopes": [
    {
      "id": "1ed9b2c9-3c57-4254-a510-c2aa2a877338",
      "name": "scopes:create",
      "displayName": "scopes:create"
    },
    {
      "id": "9291cb11-6df3-448e-9526-e5eaff77eae8",
      "name": "scopes:view",
      "displayName": "scopes:view"
    }
  ],
  "decisionStrategy": "UNANIMOUS"
}
```

In my .net core 7 application, I made the following definitions in the Program.cs class.

```
#region Keycloak JWT
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
      .AddJwtBearer(options =>
      {
          options.Authority = "http://localhost:8080/realms/test-v1";
          options.Audience = "app_client";
          options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
          options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
          {
              ValidateIssuer = false,
              ValidateAudience = false,
              ValidateLifetime = false,
              ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
              ValidIssuer = "http://localhost:8080/realms/test-v1",
              ValidAudience = "app_client",
              IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Q0uDCeAHiPMwFdRCBHktn27YYxhU2Id1"))
          };
      });
#region Policy ayarları
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy => { policy.RequireRole("admin"); });

    options.AddPolicy("Agent", policy => { policy.RequireRole("agent"); });

    options.AddPolicy("Super_admin", policy => { policy.RequireRole("super_admin"); });

    options.AddPolicy("Admin or Super_admin or Agent", policy => { policy.RequireRole("admin", "super_admin", "agent"); });

    options.AddPolicy("report-create", policy => { policy.RequireClaim("scope", "res:report", "scopes:create"); policy.RequireRole("super_admin"); });

    options.AddPolicy("report-view", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireClaim("scope", "res:report", "scopes:view");
        policy.RequireRole("admin", "super_admin", "agent");
    });

    options.AddPolicy("account-create", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireClaim("scope", "res:account", "scopes:create");
        policy.RequireRole("admin");
    });

    options.AddPolicy("bot-view", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireClaim("scope", "res:bot", "scopes:view");
        policy.RequireRole("admin", "super_admin", "agent");
    });

    options.AddPolicy("bot-create", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireClaim("scope", "res:bot", "scopes:create");
        policy.RequireRole("admin");
    });

    options.AddPolicy("account-view", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireClaim("scope", "res:account", "scopes:view");
        policy.RequireRole("admin", "super_admin", "agent");
    });
});

#endregion
#endregion
```

I have given all privileges to the user I have specified.

The token information "on the keycloak" of the user I have determined is as follows.

```
{
  "exp": 1686585495,
  "iat": 1686585195,
  "jti": "0d21fef5-a123-42ca-93ac-c7f4638ee601",
  "aud": "app_client",
  "sub": "b15ff366-3ce8-408f-96a4-3b36e15bc53a",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "app_client",
  "session_state": "6a93ad50-cef3-4e36-873a-10ec69fbeac4",
  "allowed-origins": [
    "*"
  ],
  "realm_access": {
    "roles": [
      "agent",
      "standard_user",
      "super_admin",
      "offline_access",
      "admin",
      "uma_authorization",
      "default-roles-test-v1"
    ]
  },
  "resource_access": {
    "account": {
      "roles": [
        "manage-account",
        "manage-account-links",
        "view-profile"
      ]
    }
  },
  "authorization": {
    "permissions": [
      {
        "scopes": [
          "scopes:create",
          "scopes:view"
        ],
        "rsid": "0190385a-890a-4876-8e07-bf29c4c91466",
        "rsname": "res:bot"
      },
      {
        "scopes": [
          "scopes:create",
          "scopes:view"
        ],
        "rsid": "7897680c-d0b6-4fba-8730-5ddbd891c68b",
        "rsname": "res:report"
      },
      {
        "scopes": [
          "scopes:create",
          "scopes:view"
        ],
        "rsid": "ecca2ad1-06ad-490e-af8a-305ebd293591",
        "rsname": "res:account"
      }
    ]
  },
  "scope": "profile email",
  "sid": "6a93ad50-cef3-4e36-873a-10ec69fbeac4",
  "email_verified": false,
  "name": "testuser001",
  "preferred_username": "testuser001",
  "given_name": "test",
  "family_name": "user"
}
```

In the Controller, I made a definition as follows.

```
[Authorize("Super_admin")]
[HttpGet]
[Route("search")]
public async Task<ActionResult<PaginatedResult<GetCompanySearchWithPaginationDto>>> GetCompanySearchQuery([FromQuery] GetCompanySearchWithPaginationQuery dto)
{
    return await _mediator.Send(dto);
}
```

I'm sending a request with Postman, but I keep getting 403 errors. The user has full privileges. Where could I have made a mistake? I couldn't understand if I am having a problem on the .net core side. I pass the tests successfully on the Keycloak side.

Comment: Unfortunately, the answers in the other post do not meet my needs, can you help?